# Deleting large number of images using PHPhotolibrary

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, photosframework, phphotolibrary

Hi i have a performance issue with the deletion of large number of images. I am using the following code for deletion.

```
    [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
         [PHAssetChangeRequest deleteAssets:assetsToBeDeleted];
    } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
         completion(success);
    }];
```

It works fine for a small set of images, without any performance issue. But when i tried with deletion of 1500 photos(including burst images), it nearly takes 20 minutes for a call back inside the completion block, which is definitely a concern. Interesting point is iOS default Photo app took less than a minute to delete this set of images. Did i miss something?

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Just make it in background thread.if you can find a way to show number photos deleted and remaining.Then show a popup,show information what is deleting and what is in the process. . . .Show progress.because in default app apple have much more access than us.example :- apple can show watch running on app icon but we cannot.Deleting will take time by PHPhotoLibrary.

Comment: Have you seen kycalc app.It gives limit to you to fetch and delete those fix amount of data from gallery

Comment: @Anil Actually i am surprised with the time taking for the deletion process. If it is normal, i am convinced. I will check  kycalc app. Thanks